What is wrong in this Proof of $c$ is divisible by the product $ab$?

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a,b$ are both factors of $c$ then prove that $ab$ is also a factor of $c$.

I have seen threads in MSE about these, and I see Bezout's Lemma is used as a tool to prove.
But why the following is wrong?
Since $a$ and $b$ are factors of $c$, we have $c=ak=bm$ for some integers $k,m$.
So we have $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{m}{k}\Rightarrow m=ar, k=br$$ for some integer $r$. So we have $$c=abr \Rightarrow ab | c$$

Your result has $r=\frac{k}{b}$. If $b\neq 0$, then this exists and is always rational, but you shouldn't just state it's also an integer. Instead, this is something that you should prove. Note this is basically what those other posts on this site that you mentioned basically do, e.g., such as by using Bézout's lemma.

@JohnOmielan I am not able to find an example, for which $r$ is non integer but rational. Can you please help?

With $\gcd(a,b)=1$, there are no examples where $r$ is non-integral since what you state is actually true. My comment was just that it's something you should prove rather than just saying it's the case. This is because, with $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1$, there are examples where $r$ is non-integral, such as with $a=6$, $b=10$ and $c=30$. Then $k=5$, with $\frac{k}{b}=\frac{5}{10}$ not being an integer.

So as far as $gcd(a,b)=1$, My proof is correct?

IMHO, it's not technically incorrect. I believe a better adjective to describe your proof is that it's incomplete.

So to make it complete, we have to use Bezout's Lemma? Thanks for your kind replies.

You're welcome. My final response here is that you should always appropriately prove whatever you state. Note that Bézout's lemma is, AFAIK, the most common, and one of the simplest, ways to do that with your particular problem, but you don't necessarily have to use it.

Your argument is the same as the common argument using EL = Euclid's Lemma (cf. here in first dupe). except you have used an equivalent fractional form of EL, viz. unique fractionization. Typically this is not found in textbooks since most authors avoid use of fractions in divisibility arguments in elementary contexts.

At this elementary level one needs to justify invocations of nontrivial (divisibility) properties of fractions such as unique fractionization. So either you must refer to a known theorem proving this or else you must prove it yourself (e.g. invoking a known theorem like Euclid's Lemma). While this property of reduced fractions may seem empirically obvious, a complete correct argument requires logical proof.  Compare discussion here of unjustified invocation of $a^2\mid b^2\Rightarrow a\mid b,$ in arguments on irrationality of square-roots.

Note that properties (like unique fractionization) that imply Euclid's Lemma also imply uniqueness of prime factorizations, a fundamental result from which follows much of the divisibility theory of integers. There are many such divisibility properties known, e.g. see the list here. Whichever of these properties one chooses as a foundation (e.g. Bezout, GCDs exist, Schreier), for an argument based on them to be well-founded, one must prove the chosen foundational property.
